# How to store a bool value true/false in database table using jQuery on show/hide button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to store Boolean value **True** if user click's on **show** button and Boolean value **False** if user clicks on **hide** button with its specific **id**(primary key) from view

What i have tried is this, but i am not getting expected result

Buttons

```
            <a href="" class="approve btn btn-default" data-id="@item.Id">Show</a> |
            <a href="" class="reject btn btn-default" data-id="@item.Id">Hide</a>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(function () {

    (".approve").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).data("id");
        $.post("@Url.Action("ShowHide", "Home")", { id: selectedId, update: true });
        $(this).hide;
    });

    (".reject").click(function () {
        var selectedId = $(this).data("id");
        $.post("@Url.Action("ShowHide", "Home")", { id: selectedId, update: false });
        $(this).hide;
    });

});
```

Controller Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool ShowHide(int id, bool update)
    {
        var user = db.UserComments.Find(id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(user))
        {
            user.IsShow = update;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: *"but i am not getting expected result"*... what result are you getting? An exception? Something else?

Comment: You're missing the `jQuery` or `$` prefix before your selectors, `(".approve").click...` You need to check the console for client side JS errors and also the response from the AJAX request - assuming it's even being sent.

Comment: i want if i click on show button in backend boolean value True should be entered in db table to that particular record and it is not updating the db table

Comment: @prathamesh93, did `bool update` in controller gives you `true` or `false` regarding button clicks?

Comment: @ershoaib  i am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: @prathamesh93, are you successfully getting the values of `id` and `update` as parameter to your `ShowHide` method.  if user click on Show then is `true` comes to parameter or vice cersa?

Comment: @ershoaib it is not even striking the breakpoints of the method when i am trying to debug it

Comment: @prathamesh93, in your browser console can u see the request is going to back end ?

Answer (score 0):

To know if an object is visible or invisible, use jQuery's `.is()` function.

**Example:**

```js
$("#check").click(function() {
  // Use ":hidden" to check if something is hidden instead of visible
  if ($("div").is(":visible")) {
    $("span").text("Visible");
  } else {
    $("span").text("Hidden");
  }
});

$("#hide").click(function() {
  $("div").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function() {
  $("div").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="check">Check</button><br> 
Check Result: <strong><span></span></strong>
```